# call middleware inside express controller

Tags: node.js, express

in my server i have a process to create a json web token and set it as a cookie after finding user from mongodb..i just create the token, calculate the cookies expiry, and set the cookie like so:

```
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            let token = createToken(user.id);
            res.cookie("userToken", token, { expires: d });
```

the problem is sometimes i need to do this process in other routes which is leaving a lot of duplicate code that is harder to change and maintain..i want to create a middleware function that i can reuse where ever i need..i'm thinking of something like so:

```
function setTokenCookie(user,req,res,next){
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    let token = createToken(user.id);
    res.cookie("userToken", token, { expires: d });
    next();
}

router.post("/route", (req, res) => {

    User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
        
                    //some code to handle user here
                    
                    setTokenCookie(user,req,res,next);
        
                    //more code process here

                    res.sendStatus(200);
                
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send(err.message);
    })
})
```

but this doesn't work..what can i do to implement my goal idea?

EDIT: by "this doesn't work" i mean that i got an error that states that "next" is not a function inside the middleware..i don't know why.
when i delete the next() line and try to run the function, the browser doesn't receive the jwt cookie afte the response is received..i don't know why is this happening

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Please be more specific. https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: question edited

Comment: Well `next` is not defined where you're trying to pass it to your `setTokenCookie()` function. You're not using this as middleware though so it's unlikely you'll want to call `next()` at all

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your own callback as the `next` argument and the middleware will tell you when it's done that way:

```
function setTokenCookie(user,req,res,next){
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    let token = createToken(user.id);
    res.cookie("userToken", token, { expires: d });
    next();
}

router.post("/route", (req, res, next) => {

    User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
        
        //some code to handle user here
                    
        setTokenCookie(user, req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
            } else {
                //more code process here

                res.sendStatus(200);
             }
         });
                
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send(err.message);
    })
});
```

---

Since your middleware is not asynchronous, you could also just factor out the core logic into its own function that you can use multiple places:

```
function setTokenCookieInternal(user, req, res) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    let token = createToken(user.id);
    res.cookie("userToken", token, { expires: d });
}


function setTokenCookie(user,req,res,next){
    setTokenCookieInternal(user, req, res);
    next();
}
```

And, then use the internal function in your route:

```
router.post("/route", (req, res) => {

    User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
        
         //some code to handle user here
                    
         setTokenCookieInternal(user, req, res);
        
         //more code process here

         res.sendStatus(200);
                
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send(err.message);
    })
});
```

---

Or, a third option is you could make your middleware so it can be used either as a function or as middleware based on whether the `next` argument is passed or not:

```
function setTokenCookie(user,req,res,next){
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    let token = createToken(user.id);
    res.cookie("userToken", token, { expires: d });

    // only call next() if the next argument was passed
    if (next) {
        next();
    }
}

router.post("/route", (req, res) => {

    User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
        
         //some code to handle user here
                    
         setTokenCookie(user, req, res);
        
         //more code process here

         res.sendStatus(200);
                
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send(err.message);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have a `next` function when you run it manually, you can do this:

1. Remove the `next` parameter from the function call

```js
setTokenCookie(user,req,res)
```

2. In `setTokenCookie`, only run the `next` function if there is one (last line)

```js
if (next) next();
```